# How to match an optional word between two other words?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Let's say I want to match words `"green apple"`. I also want to match words like `"green big apple"`.

How to write regular expression for this?

I wrote `r"green [a-z+] apple"`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: are are only matching a single letter, maybe you want to match zero or more letters

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: The first text is a subset of the second. To make a single regex to match both, the two strings can be joined then factored. `green[ ](?:big[ ])?apple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but your `+` is inside the `[]` instead of outside, and also the word may not exist so you need to wrap the entire thing (and one of the spaces) in a `?`, to match one word or no word (can replace with `*` for any number of middle words).

```py
import re

pattern =  r"green ([a-z]+ )?apple"
print(re.match(pattern, "green apple").group(0))
print(re.match(pattern, "green big apple").group(0))
```

Output:

```
green apple
green big apple
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pattern

This should work fine .

```js
/(green)(.+)(apple)/
```

The answer to your question is not simple because you need to decide how you want to handle different scenarios. For example:

- Do you want to capture everything in between the word "green" and "apple"?
- Are capture groups relevant, or do you simply want to know if the two words occur in the given sequence where "green" comes before "apple"?
- Is the sequence of said words even important, and do they have to occur in pairs, i.e. for every occurrence of "green" does there have to be one of "apple"?

### Matching example

Below is an example of what the pattern will capture.

**green apple**

**green big apple**

banana **green small blueberry apple** orange strawberry